# Skill-set is not common in or on

Tags: prepositions

I've written the following sentence but after reading it, it sounds to me like it's wrong.

> The skill-set for iOS and Android development is not common in the current team.

Is it correct to say "common **in** the current team"? Or should I use "common **on**"?

Comment: It's polite and helpful to explain *why* it sounds to you like it's wrong.

Comment: I don't know, really. Just feeling that "skill-set" is not something that is found "in" people, rather like someone that people "have".

Comment: The *team* is not individual people -- even otherwise, "one has to have it **in** him".

Comment: There are other candidate prepositions, too, like _among_ and _within_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s *in*. However, you may want to consider re-writing the whole thing. Something like this might be clearer, depending on how polite you want to be:

> Most of those working on the project are not familiar with iOS and
>   Android development.